Select 2 rows with multiple columns into a single row with multiple columns from one table
the table is this:



ID
Name
Serial
SentYN
Data
Type




1
test1
SerialA
1
2024-06-20
EX1


2
test2
SerialB
0
2024-06-19
Ex2



I want this result please:



ID1
ID2
Name1
Name2
Serial1
Serial2
SentYN2
SentYN2
Data1
Data2
Type1
Type2




1
2
test1
test2
SerialA
SerialB
1
0
2024-06-20
2024-06-19
EX1
Ex2



I try this:
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Type = 'EX1' THEN ID END AS ID1,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'EX2' THEN ID END AS ID2,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'EX1' THEN Name END AS Name1,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'EX2' THEN Name END AS Name2,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'EX1' THEN Serial END AS Serial1,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'EX2' THEN Serial END AS Serial2,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'EX1' THEN SentYN END  AS SentYN1,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'EX2' THEN SentYN END  AS SentYN2,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'EX1' THEN Data END AS Data1,
        CASE WHEN Type = 'EX2' THEN Data END AS Data2,
FROM table WITH (NOLOCK)


Add MAX(<your case when>) around every column in your sql and move on to the next target. This will get tedious if you have more than 2 rows, for that read about pivots. You should then realize noone wants to look at the data this way because each grouping expands the columns

Does this answer your question? Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns
